# Can an application consume its own published messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, publish-subscribe

My question is whether it makes sense to publish a huge amount of streaming data to the same application which is also the consumer of those messages. Does asynchronous nature of queue messaging systems like RabbitMQ helps with the performance in such conditions?

Example: if a huge amount of streaming data comes into the service, will sending them into a queue in RabbitMQ and processing them (Listening) one by one from the same application make sense?

Comment: I've removed the Kafka tag since you don't seem to be exclusively asking about it. But the answer to your question 1) it can consume, yes, but 2) "makes sense" depends if **other applications** are interested in the same data. Otherwise, why asynchronously send to a remote queue rather than use faster in memory buffers?

Comment: *make sense* here is very subjective, and also depends on what the application is doing. I'm voting to close this question as it lacks focus. Please update it with more specific details about your use-case to make the question objectively answerable.

Comment: @OneCricketeer If the number of messages getting received from the stream is very high then using in memory buffer does not make sense and some sort of distributed asynchronisity will be needed.

Comment: @super my question was general and simple, but for you to be able to understand it, I have added an example.

Comment: @parsa The issue is that it's too general. Your addition didn't help.

Comment: Any messaging consumer that pulls data will populate in-memory queues before handling the events. Threads can be used for distribution. Same could be said for a database client, so the question isn't  really unique to message queues, I feel. Database applications write and query the database themselves, too